# Running AWS EMR Spark: java.io.FileNotFoundException ... io.netty_netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.59.Final.jar does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

When trying to run a Spark 3.0.1 job on AWS emr-6.1.0, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/io.netty_netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.59.Final.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.distribute$1(Client.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$23(Client.scala:615)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$22(Client.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$22$adapted(Client.scala:613)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at com.semanticbits.App$.main(App.scala:23)
    at com.semanticbits.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1024)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was using version 2 of the AWS Java SDK to pull some parameters from the AWS Parameter Store.  For some reason emr-6.1.0 only supports version 1.  Once I switched my dependency to the older SDK, the error was resolved.